# How do I find all instances that have field: "username" inequivalent to its stripped "username"

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

In a pseudo-query, it would look something like this:

```
User.objects.filter(username != username.strip())
```

Example usernames that would match this search:
"hello "
" hello"
" hello "

Example usernames that would NOT match this search:
"hello"
"hello world"

Examples are not exhaustive (i.e. the whitespace can be in the form of tabs, newlines, etc).

Comment: Do you mean to search users with username empty or to be more specific, only blank spaces in username?

Comment: @rkatkam I do not meant that. I've added examples if it was unclear.

Comment: @rkatkam from docs "strip([chars])
Return a copy of the sequence with specified leading and trailing bytes removed"

Comment: Question: what's the purpose of your query? If it's a one time thing, maybe it would be easier to just fetch everything and compare in python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you storing usernames in your database with leading and trailing spaces? Trim them before you insert them instead of allowing dirty data in your database.

But to answer your question directly, you don't need to use `extra` to do a regular expression lookup, as the queryset API [natively supports it](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#regex).

This should do what you want:

```py
User.objects.filter(username__regex=r"\s*" + user + r"\s*")
```

Things get a little messy on SQLLite, where regex lookups aren't natively supported, but it still works.

Comment: My purpose is to clean a database that has already been dirtied.

Comment: Got it! In that case, just curious, if the intention is to clean the dirty data,  why wouldn't a simple `for u in User.objects.all(): u.username = u.username.strip(); u.save()` wouldn't work to do the cleaning? Assuming the username field is unique, do you have users with the same username save for the whitespace? If so, bummer! That's really an entirely different problem.

Answer (score 1):

[extra](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#extra) can be used. This is what it would look like for PostgreSQL:

```
User.objects.extra(where=["username != regexp_replace(username, '^\s+|\s+$', '', 'g')"])
```

Comment: it seems that extra is having trouble comparing a field against itself.

Comment: Updated the answer to match tabs, newlines, etc. `extra` shouldn't really have a problem with comparing a field with itself. It basically just allows inserting some raw sql. What's the db engine you use?

Comment: The regexp_replace will be a problem in MySQL. Off the top of my head, the example for MySQL would be `User.objects.extra(where=["username != TRIM(Replace(Replace(Replace(username,'\t',''),'\n',''),'\r',''))"])`

Comment: Doh. My usernames are encrypted in my db. I would like to accept your previous answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/0571bd12-d34d-4f6f-a77c-4a4d09680117/view-source

Comment: Thing is that answer only takes care of spaces, it will ignore tabs and newlines.

Comment: hm. Alright. Others should look at the question's edit history for other ideas. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.db.models import Q

User.objects.filter(Q(username__startswith=' ') | Q(username__endswith=' '))
```